# What does "country fellows" actually mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

I searched on Internet for *country fellows*, but I couldn't find definition. What is the origin and the real meaning of *country fellows*?

**Edit:**
I didn't mean "fellow countrymen". does this phrase have a double meaning? Because I heard it in a bad context. If a guy did something unnatural they call him with pity.

Comment: You don't mean "fellow countrymen"?

Comment: What is the context of the phrase?

Comment: No, I didn't mean "fellow countrymen". does this phrase have a double meaning? because i heard it in a bad context. if a guy did something unnatural they call him with pity.

Comment: This question can't be answered definitively without more (read: at least an inkling of) context, but my first thought was *country fellows* as opposed to *city folk* -- i.e. this might be a different way of saying *country bumpkins*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I've tried to find references and *failed*. I can share my personal experience here, though, assuming the OP is a fellow Indian.

**"Country fellow"** is a *slightly offensive* phrase in south India. It is merely a direct translation of the words from south Indian languages (Malayalam, Tamil, etc.), for example, "naadan chekkan" in Malayalam.

It has nothing to do with the original meaning of *fellow countrymen*. What it actually means is a person who is [**cultureless**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cultureless); or someone **not** [**trendy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trendy) enough (among a group of friends, mostly).

Suppose three friends are discussing western music (say, a rap song by Eminem). If one of them tells that he likes Indian [carnatic music](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Carnatic) more, then the other two might say "Oh, grow up! Don't be such a country fellow".

I hope my explanation is clear. I couldn't find any reliable reference to add here. Perhaps it's enough that searching ["country fellows" on google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=country%20fellows%20meaning&oq=country%20fellows%20meaning) will have results related to south Indian slang.

It can also mean "people from the countryside", but that doesn't usually apply when used among friends.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a band by this name; in that context it probably means "fellows from the country", i.e. men or friends from the countryside. This probably refers to Country music.

Other than that, I think this word is only used by non-native speakers, as a variation of "fellow countrymen": I do not believe this to be an actual native English word or expression. I have only found it on foreign websites whose English was of questionable quality.

Comment: As the band is a Country & Western band, I think that *Country* in it's name primally refers to the music style.

Comment: @Gufa: You're absolutely right! I should have mentioned that. It's just that I am not a particular fan of the genre...

Answer (score 1):

As adjective, *fellow* means "being of the same kind, group, occupation, society, or locality".

> They urged the troops not to fire on their fellow citizens.

*Fellows* can be used as noun to mean "who is of the same kind, group, occupation, society or locality".
Informally, *fellow* means also "man or boy".

**<sub>[Example taken from the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.]</sub>**

Comment: I can understand both country and fellow separately. In my region "country fellow" is used in a "bad" sense of context. both are good meaning but when combined i don't know why it gives a bad meaning :(

Comment: @mahesh: When used in a derogatory way, it means *people from the countryside*, and implies that people from the city would be more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

The most common meaning is *people (friends) from the same country (nation)*.

Due to the multiple meanings of both *country* and *fellows*, it could take other meanings in certain situations. *Country* could be a nation, it could be the countryside i.e. non-urban regions, or it could be the music style Country and Western. *Fellows* could mean friends, but also just a group of persons. There is for example a Country and Western band called *Country Fellows*.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Not my down vote, but I think you and OP aren't on the same page with this. See my answer, for example.

Answer (score -1):

People from the same country or community are called ***country fellows***.

This is similar to *class fellows* for people that attended the same school.